# Symfony2 - @Assert\Email() changes field height

Tags: symfony, constraints, assert, validation

i'm using @Assert\Email to validate an email field, but it looks like it changes the fields appearence even if it' really doesn't... The css style is still there although somehow for an unknown reason (to me at least) the field looks smaller, in height. Is there anyway to avoid this?

Example:

[image: photo]

Comment: What type is the generated field? in one case "text" in the other "email"? Does this happens in all browsers? What happens if you disable CSS completely? Some more details would be nice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a custom Regex

```
 @Assert\Regex(pattern="/[a-zA-Z0-9\_\-]+[a-zA-Z0-9\.\_\-]*@([a-zA-Z0-9\_\-]+\.)+([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|travel|museum)$/")
```